# Insertion of 500 simple rows taking over 40 seconds in MySql

Tags: mysql, performance, ubuntu, query-performance, mysql-5.7

We have a simple table without neither foreign keys nor primary keys (for this test). All columns are int or tinyint except for p whose type is decimal(5,4).

Below is part of the query we are running. It takes 40 seconds to finish.

We are running this from Phpmyadmin now. But the problem appeared while testing our Laravel application that was taking far too much time to complete this simple task.

Our table configuration is:
InnoDB - Row Format: DYNAMIC - Latin1_Swedish_ci

Mysql Version: 5.7.31-0ubuntu0.18.04.1
Running on Ubuntu Server.

```
DELETE FROM test WHERE species_id = 290;

INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 16);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 15);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 14);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 11);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 17);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 13);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 99999);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 5);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 29);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 21);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 38);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 7);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 30);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 6);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 37);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 40);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 36);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100003);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100008);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100015);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 8);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 2);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 39);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 1);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 42);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 4);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100016);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 28);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 12);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 26);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 24);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 23);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100000);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 25);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 9);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 22);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 18);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 10);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100005);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 20);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100002);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 27);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 19);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 3);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 35);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100004);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100007);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100006);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 34);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 33);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100010);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100011);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100009);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100012);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100014);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 100013);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 32);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 1, 0, 31);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 16);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 15);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 14);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 11);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 17);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 13);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 99999);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 5);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 29);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 21);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 38);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 7);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 30);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 6);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 37);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 40);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 36);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 100003);
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES (290, 2, 0, 100008);
```

...

Comment: The primary key`(species_id, month, beta_set_id)` is not sequential，which will lead [page split](https://www.percona.com/blog/2017/04/10/innodb-page-merging-and-page-splitting).Having a sequential primary key will save a lot of inserting time.

Comment: First, we need that or at least we need that to be a unique key. But anyway, we just removed the PK and still takes the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL is not particularly fast at doing inserts one at a time; there's a lot of overhead for each request.  Batch them, like:

```
INSERT INTO test (species_id, month, p, beta_set_id) VALUES
(290, 1, 0, 16),
(290, 1, 0, 15),
(290, 1, 0, 14),
(290, 1, 0, 11),
(290, 1, 0, 17),
(290, 1, 0, 13),
(290, 1, 0, 99999),
(290, 1, 0, 5),
(290, 1, 0, 29),
(290, 1, 0, 21),
(290, 1, 0, 38),
(290, 1, 0, 7),
(290, 1, 0, 30),
(290, 1, 0, 6),
(290, 1, 0, 37),
(290, 1, 0, 40),
(290, 1, 0, 36),
(290, 1, 0, 100003),
(290, 1, 0, 100008),
(290, 1, 0, 100015),
(290, 1, 0, 8),
(290, 1, 0, 2),
(290, 1, 0, 39),
(290, 1, 0, 1),
(290, 1, 0, 42),
(290, 1, 0, 4),
(290, 1, 0, 100016),
(290, 1, 0, 28),
(290, 1, 0, 12),
(290, 1, 0, 26),
(290, 1, 0, 24),
(290, 1, 0, 23),
(290, 1, 0, 100000),
(290, 1, 0, 25),
(290, 1, 0, 9),
(290, 1, 0, 22),
(290, 1, 0, 18),
(290, 1, 0, 10),
(290, 1, 0, 100005),
(290, 1, 0, 20),
(290, 1, 0, 100002),
(290, 1, 0, 27),
(290, 1, 0, 19),
(290, 1, 0, 3),
(290, 1, 0, 35),
(290, 1, 0, 100004),
(290, 1, 0, 100007),
(290, 1, 0, 100006),
(290, 1, 0, 34),
(290, 1, 0, 33),
(290, 1, 0, 100010),
(290, 1, 0, 100011),
(290, 1, 0, 100009),
(290, 1, 0, 100012),
(290, 1, 0, 100014),
(290, 1, 0, 100013),
(290, 1, 0, 32),
(290, 1, 0, 31),
(290, 2, 0, 16),
(290, 2, 0, 15),
(290, 2, 0, 14),
(290, 2, 0, 11),
(290, 2, 0, 17),
(290, 2, 0, 13),
(290, 2, 0, 99999),
(290, 2, 0, 5),
(290, 2, 0, 29),
(290, 2, 0, 21),
(290, 2, 0, 38),
(290, 2, 0, 7),
(290, 2, 0, 30),
(290, 2, 0, 6),
(290, 2, 0, 37),
(290, 2, 0, 40),
(290, 2, 0, 36),
(290, 2, 0, 100003),
(290, 2, 0, 100008);
```

As long as the full insert statement is less than @@max_allowed_packet (typically at least a million), you can insert as many rows as you need.  Programmatically, split it up into batches of 1000 rows, if needed.

Comment: So you are saying that this makes it take 40 seconds?

Comment: The problem is, what happens if I really need to do 500 inserts with some SELECTs between each INSERT?

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson very likely.  try it and see.

Comment: you can't do the selects ahead of time?  is this all in a transaction?

Comment: the post here was a simplification. But our real app is doing selects between each insert. So I'm not sure if I'll be able to apply this becase I think some values will depend on previous inserts... If you have some suggestion please let me know. Thanks

Comment: 500 is not that many; seems like you could not actually do the inserts but adjust the intermediate selects by whatever effect the inserts would have had then do the inserts all at the end?  I don't have anything else to suggest

Comment: A Rule of Thumb -- batching 100 `INSERTs` like shown here will run **10 times as fast** as the original 1-row-at-a-time.  (More than 100 at a time gives "diminishing returns"; less than 100 gives less than 10x.)